# Inheritance same variable name amongst siblings

Tags: c++

I'm having trouble testing if variables with the same name are unique to seperate classes.

This is my example:

```
class Sprite
{
public 
    int maxHP;
    virtual void setup()=0
};

class Hero : public Sprite
{
    void setup(){maxHP = 100;}
};
class Monster : public Sprite
    void setup(){maxHP = 60;}
};
```

Do both of my sprites have 0 hp? Do the variables override each other?
Do I have to use this-> keyword to make them all specific?

Thanks.

Comment: Good programming practice: In inherited classes, always use `this->`. It's not a big deal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a variable type of `Sprite` and do not specialize it (like `Hero` or `Monster`), yes it has 0 HP. But If you create a pointer which is type `Sprite` and which holds the adress of specific type; then its HP is speciliazed too. I mean:

```
Sprite *S; //the pointer
Hero Johny;
S = &Johny;

S->setup(); // Johny's HP is updated to 100
```